# Android Here-API :How to add buttons to a Here maps infobubble

Tags: android, here-api, infobubble

Is it possible to add a  button to a Here maps info-bubble. I checked Android here maps api but did not find any thing useful. Just wondering if any one has tried this before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use InfoBubbleAdapter to set bubble layout :

```
Map hMap.setInfoBubbleAdapter(new Map.InfoBubbleAdapter() {
            @Override
            public View getInfoBubbleContents(MapMarker mapMarker) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoBubble(final MapMarker mapMarker) {
                View bubble;
                bubble = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.tooltip_cluster, container, false);
                Button btn = (Button) bubble.findViewById(R.id.btnBubble);
                return bubble;
            }
        });
```

and define button in your layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#00f">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Hello World !"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="#c0392b"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnBubble"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="click ME !"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```